# Bitcoin Core - create new receiving address with PHP

Tags: bitcoin-core, php

I have Bitcoin Core on Debian

[image: Bitcoin Core]

Need to create new receiving address with PHP.

As you see at screenshot, I've try to create new address from terminal, but that does not added at Bitcoin Core Receiving Address List, address created but, it's address list empty again.

Need that way which can give me new address and also it inserted in "Requested payments history".

Is it possible with PHP? If yes please explain me how it is possible. Please do not send me only links: EasyBitcoin, Bit-Wasp, etc.

Is it possible with this "denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc" and if yes, please help to to understand how it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Need that way which can give me new address and also it inserted in "Requested payments history

New address created with `getnewaddress` RPC command will be visible in 'receiving addresses'. I have created 2 addresses from CLI with `getnewaddress`.

[image: receiving-addresses]

Address created using 'Create new receiving address' button can have more information associated with it (date, message, amount etc.) which is saved in 'Requested payments history'. `bcrt1qe4ryqy8lv59na0wkm6y96p8tu9njjlkme32szz` in 'receiving addresses' was created using this option.

[image: payment-history]

> Is it possible with PHP?

Yes you can create new address with PHP:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:18333/wallet/P1',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getnewaddress", "params": []}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz',
    'Content-Type: text/plain'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

RPC credentials used in above code:

```
regtest.rpcport=18333
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This is what I want. I appreciate that.

Comment: One question please, how do you get Authorization Basic? I mean "dXNlcjpwYXNz"

Comment: `$rpc_credentials = 'user:pass'; echo base64_encode($rpc_credentials);`